# GLSurfaceView using OpenGL ES 2.0 shows blank screen for certain users

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a longstanding issue in one of my published Android games where certain users see nothing rendered in the `GLSurfaceView` where the gameplay takes place. I've never been able to reproduce the issue on any of my own test devices so it's been extremely difficult to debug.

Recently I was able to work with one of the users who reported the bug in order to isolate it to a pretty small subset of code. Unfortunately at this point it's not very different from the basic tutorial samples, so I'm somewhat at a loss for what could be going wrong.

The code below should draw a white square in the center of the screen. It works fine on my test devices, but fails for this user (and presumably also fails for the numerous other users who have reported the same bug to me).

I've tried a few different tests already. A change of the background color is visible to the user, so this isn't a blanket failure of all GL calls. Additionally, when I inserted extra calls to glCheckError I never logged any nonzero return.

Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GLSurfaceView view = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.gl);
        view.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        view.setRenderer(new GLRenderer());
        view.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

        view.requestRender();
    }

    private static class GLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
        public static final float SCALE = 480f;
        private float ratio;

        private int mProgram;
        private int mPositionHandle;
        private int mColorHandle;
        private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

        private final float[] mVMatrix = new float[16];   // View matrix
        private final float[] mPMatrix = new float[16];   // Projection matrix
        private final float[] mVPMatrix = new float[16];  // V * P
        private final float[] mMMatrix = new float[16];   // Object transformation matrix (position/rotation)
        private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16]; // VP * M

        private final float[] foregroundColor = {1f, 1f, 1f, 1f};
        private final float[] backgroundColor = {0f, 0f, 0f, 1f};

        private static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
        private static final int VERTEX_STRIDE = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

        private final float[] points = {
                -20, -20, 0,
                -20, 20, 0,
                20, -20, 0,
                20, 20, 0
        };
        private final short[] drawOrder = {
                0, 1, 2, 3
        };

        private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = buildFloatBuffer(points);
        private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer = buildShortBuffer(drawOrder);

        private static FloatBuffer buildFloatBuffer(float[] array) {
            FloatBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                    // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                    array.length * 4)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                    .asFloatBuffer()
                    .put(array)
                    ;
            buffer.position(0);
            return buffer;
        }

        private static ShortBuffer buildShortBuffer(short[] array) {
            ShortBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                    // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
                    array.length * 2)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                    .asShortBuffer()
                    .put(array)
                    ;
            buffer.position(0);
            return buffer;
        }

        private static final String vertexShaderCode =
                "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                "}";


        private static final String fragmentShaderCode =
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                "}";

        private static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){
            // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
            // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
            int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

            // add the source code to the shader and compile it
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

            return shader;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
            GLES20.glClearColor(backgroundColor[0], backgroundColor[1], backgroundColor[2], backgroundColor[3]);

            int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                    vertexShaderCode);
            int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                    fragmentShaderCode);

            mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
            GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);
            GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

            mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
            mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
            mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
            ratio = 1f * width / height;

            GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

            Matrix.frustumM(mPMatrix, 0, -ratio * SCALE/2, ratio * SCALE/2, -SCALE/2, SCALE/2, 3, 7);
            Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0);
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mVPMatrix, 0, mPMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

            GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, foregroundColor, 0);
            draw(0, 0, 0);

            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        }

        private void draw(float x, float y, float a) {
            Matrix.setIdentityM(mMMatrix, 0);
            Matrix.translateM(mMMatrix, 0, x, y, 0);
            Matrix.rotateM(mMMatrix, 0, a, 0, 0, 1);
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mVPMatrix, 0, mMMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE,
                    vertexBuffer);

            GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,
                    drawListBuffer.capacity(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                    drawListBuffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem goes away if I change the `Matrix.frustumM()` call to `Matrix.orthoM()`. Beyond that, I'm still unsure why things were working on some devices and not others. I'd be willing to accept another answer if anyone comes along who better understands what was going on here, but for now I've solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The driver may be buggy.  You can contact the driver company and file a bug report

Ask yourself the following questions:

1. Does the phone have a different driver? Does it support OpenGL ES 2.0?
2. Are the GL operations successful?  i.e. is glGetError() ever non-zero?
3. Is glClearColor successful? Try clearing the colour to red. Do you see a red screen?
4. Does the program successfully compile?

Comment: I've edited the question to address points 2 and 3, which I also thought to test after posting this question. As to driver issues, I don't really have any direct access to driver information, but assuming the Google Play Store filters things correctly all my users' devices should have OpenGL ES 2.0 support.

Comment: It could possibly be an issue with endianness (byte ordering).  The endianness of the driver may be different from the endianness of the device.  This shouldn't happen, but it's worth checking. Try setting the buffers to LITTE_ENDIAN or BIG_ENDIAN.

Comment: No luck with endianness, but I did figure it out! See answer I posted.